# Jquery toggle functions

Tags: jquery, sorting, toggle

I've a code to sort table using Jquery.I use toggle function to alternate clicks,and toggle beetween 'ascend' and 'descend' sort.Once you click header's table it should sort it contents.

However,there's a bug:

I click once,it sorts,then when i click again,nothing happens.I need to click again (second time) to execute the second function,and sort again.

Toggle should switch functions with single clicks,not double,am i right?

Here is the code:

```
 firstRow.toggle(function() {
        $(this).find("th:first").removeClass("ascendFirst").addClass("descendFirst");
        $(this).find("th:not(first)").removeClass("ascend").addClass("descend");

        sorted = $.makeArray($("td:eq(0)", "tr")).sort().reverse();
        sorted2 = $.makeArray($("td:eq(1)", "tr")).sort().reverse();
        sorted3 = $.makeArray($("td:eq(2)", "tr")).sort().reverse();

        for (var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
            $("td", "tr:eq(" + (i + 1) + ")").remove();
            $("tr:eq(" + (i + 1) + ")").append($("<td></td>").text($(sorted[i]).text()));


            $("tr:eq(" + (i + 1) + ")").append($("<td></td>").text($(sorted2[i]).text()));


            $("tr:eq(" + (i + 1) + ")").append($("<td></td>").text($(sorted3[i]).text()));

        }
    }, function() {
        $(this).find("th:first").removeClass("descendFirst").addClass("ascendFirst");
        $(this).find("th:not(first)").removeClass("descend").addClass("ascend");

        sorted = $.makeArray($("td:eq(0)", "tr")).sort();
        sorted2 = $.makeArray($("td:eq(1)", "tr")).sort();
        sorted3 = $.makeArray($("td:eq(2)", "tr")).sort();

        for (var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
            $("td", "tr:eq(" + (i + 1) + ")").remove();
            $("tr:eq(" + (i + 1) + ")").append($("<td></td>").text($(sorted[i]).text()));


            $("tr:eq(" + (i + 1) + ")").append($("<td></td>").text($(sorted2[i]).text()));


            $("tr:eq(" + (i + 1) + ")").append($("<td></td>").text($(sorted3[i]).text()));

        }
    });
```

Comment: Why not use tablesorter instead of rolling your own version: http://tablesorter.com/

Comment: cause,i need to learn to sort by myself

Comment: Very nice, Oz. I'm getting tired of people pointing me toward other plugins. Nobody ever learned anything by using other people's creations without asking how they worked.

Comment: there was a logic error,i dont need to switch beetween those functions to sort.I just need to call sort().reverse() every time,thk all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your toggle code looks OK. When I have had a situation where it takes a second click to get the event to fire, it has been the case that I have applied the toggle twice to the selector (in this case **firstRow**). Or that there is more than one jQuery object.

Check that you have not applied it twice, or attach your code to a simple **div** to test if it is working independently of the **firstRow** selector. eg:

```
 $("div.testclass").toggle(function() {
    // do this
    }
}, function() {
   // undo this
    }
});​
```

We may need to see your HTML too.

Answer (score 0):

From your post, it sounds like things would behave as you expected if you waited longer between your first and second click.  The double-click function could be eating your second click if you do it too soon.  If that is the case, bind this handler to both the click and double-click events, then treat them as if they were the same event.